# Replace some rows following a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

So, I have two tables as the following:
"**Sample**"

```
sample_id|measure_id|depth|date
   11    |  1       |  0  |2013
   17    |  1       |  1  |2013
   18    |  1       | 3.5 |2013
   21    |  2       |  0  |2015
   22    |  2       |  1  |2015
```

this table contains information about existing samples measured. the sample_id is unique for each sample measured, the measure_id is the same for every "measuring campaign" the depth and the date.

The other table: "**Sample_details**", contains information about "the things that were measured for each depth":

```
parameter_id|sample_id|value
4512        |   11    |2,45
4513        |   11    |1,58
4512        |   17    |2.11     
4533        |   17    |5.36   
4512        |   18    |3,45
4518        |   18    |7,52
4512        |   21    |9,21
4513        |   21    |5,12  
4515        |   21    |5,12  
4512        |   22    |5,12  
4513        |   22    |5,12
```

The thing i am trying to do is to move all the sampling details of the depth 0 into the sampling details corresponding to depth 1. (we assume that there is always a sample of depth 0 and another one of depth 1).

I tried to reason like this:

> get sample_id from sample table where depth = 1 and replace with it the sample_id in sample_details table wherever sample_id is equal to sample_id from sample table with depth 0. (I need to do this for every measure_id, because every measure id has 0 depth and 1 depth values,... )

MY SQL Trial:

```
UPDATE SDetails 
SET SDetails.sample_id = Sample.sample_id
FROM Sample_details  SDetails
JOIN Sample Sample
ON Sample.sample_id IN (select distinct Sample.sample_id from Sample, table2  where Sample.depth = 1 AND Sample.id2 = table2.id2)
AND SDetails.sample_id IN (select Sample.sample_id from Sample, table2  where sample.depth =0 AND Sample.id2 = table2.id2)
```

The sample_details table should look like this:

```
parameter_id|sample_id|value
4512        |   17    |2,45
4513        |   17    |1,58
4512        |   17    |2.11     
4533        |   17    |5.36   
4512        |   18    |3,45
4518        |   18    |7,52
4512        |   22    |9,21
4513        |   22    |5,12  
4515        |   22    |5,12  
4512        |   22    |5,12  
4513        |   22    |5,12
```

Comment: Why bother writing an alias that is the same as the name of the table? And you should start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around for 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins As to the question at hand...it is not at all clear what the issue is. Here is a great place to start improving your question. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Really? is it not clear what the issue is? :D wow

Comment: No.. not at all clear... could you please post an 'after' version of you sample details table so we see what the result should be? Including a row for ALL samples in both the before and after, so we can see how you want the different permutations handled.

Comment: I'd love to help, but I'm staring at your before/after and I still have no idea what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I've read this 5 times now, and I still don't quite get it.

Comment: Yet i tried to be as clear as possible :D. So i changed it a little bit now

Comment: This just makes no sense at all. Your tables don't have anything that can tie one to another. There are duplicates with both parameters and samples. But the values column has moved from one sample to another with no explanation why.

Comment: Super confusing... but it basically sounds like you just want to change all depts of 0 to 1 which is easy with an update statement. You don't have to mess with the details table at all `update sample set depth = 1 where depth = 0`. Though, this is probably pointless. I assume you are aggregating some data and want to treat 0 and 1 as the same for the depths. In that case, it's a conditional aggregation.

Comment: @scsimon exactly! i need a conditional aggregation, but i have no idea how.

Comment: Hi @user2019747! Will samples only ever contain *one* row per measure_id + depth pair?

Comment: Hello @BenGribaudo YES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Sample TABLE(sample_id INT, measure_id INT, depth FLOAT, [date] INT)
INSERT INTO @Sample (sample_id, measure_id, depth, [date])

SELECT 11, 1, 0, 2013
UNION ALL
SELECT 17, 1, 1, 2013
UNION ALL
SELECT 18, 1, 3.5, 2013
UNION ALL
SELECT 21, 2, 0, 2015
UNION ALL
SELECT 22, 2, 1, 2015

DECLARE @sample_details TABLE (parameter_id INT, sample_id INT, value VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @sample_details (parameter_id, sample_id, value)

SELECT 4512, 11, '2,45'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4513, 11, '1,58'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4512, 17, '2.11'     
UNION ALL
SELECT 4533, 17, '5.36'   
UNION ALL
SELECT 4512, 18, '3,45'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4518, 18, '7,52'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4512, 21, '9,21'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4513, 21, '5,12'  
UNION ALL
SELECT 4515, 21, '5,12'  
UNION ALL
SELECT 4512, 22, '5,12'  
UNION ALL
SELECT 4513, 22, '5,12'

DECLARE @tmp TABLE (oldvalue INT, newvalue INT)
INSERT INTO @tmp(oldvalue, newvalue)
SELECT s1.sample_id, s2.sample_id
FROM @Sample s1
    INNER JOIN @Sample s2 ON s2.measure_id = s1.measure_id
WHERE s1.depth = 0
    AND s2.depth = 1


UPDATE sd
SET sd.sample_id = tmp.newvalue
FROM @sample_details sd
    INNER JOIN @tmp tmp ON tmp.oldvalue = sd.sample_id

SELECT * FROM @sample_details
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

1. Find all *sample + sample_details* pairs where the sample has a `depth = 0`.
2. Then, for each pair, find the corresponding `depth = 1` *sample*.
3. Then, update the *sample_detail*s from step 1 with the `depth = 1` *sample_id*s found in step 2.

T-SQL:

```
UPDATE d
  SET d.sample_id = s1.sample_id
FROM sample_details d
  JOIN sample s0 ON d.sample_id = s0.sample_id
    AND s0.depth = 0
  JOIN sample s1 ON s0.measure_id = s1.measure_id
    AND s1.depth = 1
```